# A proof of Tychonoff Theorem from Munkres

Tags: general-topology

It's a proof using well-ordering theorem, we can find it in Munkres 37.5
At first, it states that there exists a linear order such that $J$ is well-ordered and has a largest element. 
My question is, how does he know that the largest element exists? I just remember the well-ordering theorem just tell us that every set has a well-order, but it doesn't guarantee that there exists a largest element under this order.

Comment: Remove one element from $J$, well order it and attach the removed element at the end.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you! I get it!